# MVVM Xamarin Forms, Best for keeping a function in memory while it awaits a several minute response from a service call

Tags: xamarin, mobile, mvvm, xamarin.forms

Scenario:

I have a call being made to a WCF service which will take several minutes to get a response.

Initially the call was being made with an action which was on the **ViewModel** which then saved an updated version of an object to a **Repository** and then the **Repository** would pass the object to the **service layer** to be sent to a **web service**.

Once done the **service layer** would return the response to the **repository** and then to the **ViewModel** which would then raise a **dialogue** to the user giving them a series of options.

Issue:

The user can goto other **views** in the app while they are waiting which would destroy the **ViewModel** which then the user would not get the message alerting them..

So in a nut shell, I need to keep whatever function receives the response from the repository in memory until its completed.

To get around this I moved the dialogue and function into the **repository** as this is a singleton so will stay in memory but that defeats **Single Responsibility** as the repositories should only be responsible for the providing of data not carrying out business logic.

I have looked into raising this through messaging centre instead but I believe that this will keep **ViewModel** in memory  and the user could make this request a few times resulting in the messaging center being called with each request.

Does anyone have a best practise for handling this scenario or any documentation they could refer me to?

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Very good question, waiting for someone to give a good anwser to this too

Comment: Have you considered a singleton (service as I see it called often in this use case) that makes the request through the appropriate layers when initiated from the VM and when it gets a response sends out message the messaging center? The VMs that are responsible for displaying a dialog could then subscribe to this message. This subscription is weak and will allow for your VM to get destroyed.

Comment: I'm not sure though that your UX design is appropriate though. A local notification may be better. This notification could then link them to a related view to see more information about the result and take any additional actions if necessary. This approach could also allow them to exit the app entirely and still be notified (granted that would be a bit more work with preventing the app from getting killed by the OS)

Comment: Could you in theory just have an endlessly running task in the background (like say a syncing task for example) that just listens either to a message or something specific to appear that triggers it to process a method to display a dialogue once it is ready?

Comment: Few good ideas here. Ill keep googling and let you know if I find a common practise. I had the idea of a separate singleton class to be responsible for tasks/functions that are independent of the view-models. Maybe adding this to a background task if it needs to remain outside of the app. Cheers again for all your help with this :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should take a look at background task. It lives outside the lifecycle of mobile app. If your process is taking several minutes it's almost impossible to relay on app itself as user can terminate it or put it to sleep anytime, and you are not able to prevent it.

Comment: That is a fair point and not something I have looked into. In this scenario I can check on login to see if the task has completed. However it would be nice if I could update the app when the task is completed for the next time they open the app. 

https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-background-tasks/

Comment: You can update your app in this case by implementing data interface between your app and external service. For example sqlite db, that will store background service result and update your app next time it is started or opened.